# Confused about MongoDB Query (PHP $and)

Tags: php, mongodb, operators

I have the following code in PHP to connect to my MongoDB instance:

```
$connection_string = "mongodb://XXXXXXX:XXXXXX@XXXXX:XXX/myDB";             
$mongo_or = new Mongo($connection_string);
$db_or = $mongo_or->selectDB("myDB");

# Pick a collection
$collection_or = $db_or->myCollection;
$findArray = array('$and' => array('user.uid' => 1, 'friend_id' => 2));
$findArray2 = array('$and' => array('user.uid' => 2, 'friend_id' => 1));
$collection_or->remove($findArray);
$collection_or->remove($findArray2);
```

This never removes any results - even know the content is still there it never get's removed.

Comment: The syntax is wrong but you don't need those $ands anyway, the default operator between array elements is $and

Answer (score 0):

if you want the good structure for a $and query just json_decode this :

```
{
"$and" : [{
  "$or" : [{
      "civility" : 2
    }, {
      "civility" : 3
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: That would be a bad structure, you don't need the `$and` there and the nested `$or` is terrible for indexing.